# In Jooq, how to make the "delete" statement return the deleted records?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

In my project, there are 2 tables, `orders` and `order_payments`.

The latter is a join table with 2 columns, `order_id` and `payment_id`.

I didn't use FK for efficiency sake.

When I delete some orders from `orders` table, I need to delete the related records from `payments` table based on the `order_id` field.

So, after the orders are deleted using the DELETE statement, I want the `order_id`s of the deleted orders to be returned, so that I can use them to retrieve the `order_payments` table and delete related records.

Could someone teach me how to do that?

I tried

```
    private List<OrdersRecord> deleteOrders(OrderQuery orderQuery, DSLContext dsl) {
        DeleteQuery<OrdersRecord> deleteQuery = dsl.deleteQuery(ORDERS);
        deleteQuery.addConditions(orderQueryConditions(orderQuery));
        deleteQuery.setReturning();
        deleteQuery.execute();
        return deleteQuery.getReturnedRecords();
    }
```

but an empty List was returned.

Where I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in MySQL 8.0.21 yet:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83139

If you know a way to do this with native MySQL (whatever version), or emulate it somehow, please document it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6865

Comment: I see. I missed the `@Support` annotation and didn't notice it is not supported by MySQL. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'on delete cascade'. So you can resolve your problem. And you don't must getting ids from first table. You just must execute delete query from first table and records from second table will deleted too.

For example:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/